# Doesnt find DbContext VS2015

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio

i install vs 2015 but now i add iwant make EF6 model From my DB when created show the refrence doesn't add in my nugget i install ef 6 but and show install in my project but i did't have entity dll on my references [image]

Comment: Add the `dll`to your references if it isn't there.

Comment: iuse nugget to install it but doesn't add dll

Comment: Was the nuget installed correctly? I suppose not, if there is no dll..

Comment: it shows entity installed